# Почему не происходит передача объекта в SecondActivity?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.setI(10);
        object.setStr("Messi");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("info",object);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

В MyObject прописал:

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {
    public int i;
    public String str;
    public MyObject(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int _i) {
        parcel.writeInt(i);
        parcel.writeString(str);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {
        // распаковываем объект из Parcel
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
    // конструктор, считывающий данные из Parcel
    public MyObject(Parcel parcel) {
        this.str = parcel.readString();
        this.i = parcel.readInt();
    }
    public String getStr(){
        return this.str;
    }
    public  int getI(){
        return this.i;
    }
    public void setStr(String s){this.str=s;}
    public void setI(int t){this.i=t;}
}
```

Наконец, SecondActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("info");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInt)).setText("int: "+ myObject.getI());
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvStr)).setText("String: "+myObject.getStr());
    }
}
```

Результат в SecondActivity:5, null. Желаемый: 10, messi. Почему не передается объект?

Comment: Может потому что Вы пишете в `Parcel` в порядке `int, String` а читаете наоборот?

Comment: @woesss прав, это же не стэк, а бинарный поток.

Comment: Спасибо, все верно